# Shopify: get URL parameters when a customer visits my shop

Tags: shopify

I need access to the URL parameters in Shopify when a customer visits my shop.
For example, the customer calls up my shop with `www.myshop.com/id=1`, I am interested in the ID.
This ID should then be added to the Shopify database after the purchase has been made.

Later I would like to read out the data in an external project and be able to determine exactly which ID generated how much sales in which period.

Can someone give me a hint how / where to start?

Answer (score 1):

There is a field called `landing_site` on the [Shopify order object](https://shopify.dev/docs/admin-api/rest/reference/orders/order#properties-2021-04) you can access via the api. That should give you the data you're after.

You can also track `UTM` codes in Shopify's built in reporting, so you may be able to leverage that without the need for an additional service.

Comment: Thank you, good idea. Possible with the specific webhook ... When the user has completed an order, the webhook is triggered to a specific url with the payload including the `landing_site`...

Comment: Yes that would work, but be careful relying purely on webhooks because Shopify will stop sending if they get consecutive failures, which can happen easily if your endpoint is unavailable for more than a few requests, so I try to use it in combination with polling.

Answer (score 0):

A possible solution would be to read the url parameters from the [Order-Webhook](https://shopify.dev/docs/admin-api/rest/reference/events/webhook) under the `referring_site`-Element. It usually looks like this:

`"referring_site": "https://{shop}.myshopify.com/products/testprodukt-1"`

But the problem is that the parameters disappear when the customer changes the page. So it is not shown on the `referring_site`-Element of the webhook.

So my plan looks like this:

Insert a [Shopify-Scripttag](https://shopify.dev/docs/admin-api/rest/reference/online-store/scripttag):

```
'scripttags' => [
    [
        'src' => 'https://{domain}/scripttags/dummy.js',
        'event' => 'onload',
        'display_scope' => 'online_store'
    ]
]
```

dummy.js:

```
// some cookie functions
function setCookie(name,value,days) {
    var expires = "";
    if (days) {
        var date = new Date();
        date.setTime(date.getTime() + (days*24*60*60*1000));
        expires = "; expires=" + date.toUTCString();
    }
    document.cookie = name + "=" + (value || "")  + expires + "; path=/";
}
function getCookie(name) {
    var nameEQ = name + "=";
    var ca = document.cookie.split(';');
    for(var i=0;i < ca.length;i++) {
        var c = ca[i];
        while (c.charAt(0)==' ') c = c.substring(1,c.length);
        if (c.indexOf(nameEQ) == 0) return c.substring(nameEQ.length,c.length);
    }
    return null;
}

//get params
const url_string = window.location.href;
const url_object = new URL(url_string);
const my_param = url_object.searchParams.get("my_param");

if (my_param != null) {
    
    //set cookie
    setCookie('my_param', my_param);

}else{

    //get cookie
    let my_param_cookie = getCookie('my_param');

    if (my_param_cookie) {

        //set params from cookie

        let url_all_params = '';
        const url_pathname = url_object.pathname;
        const url_params = url_object.search;
        const url_seperator = url_params == '' ? '?' : '&';
        const url_my_param = my_param == null ? 'my_param=' + my_param_cookie : my_param;

        url_all_params = url_pathname + url_params + url_seperator + url_my_param;

        if (history.pushState) {
            window.history.pushState({}, "", url_all_params);
        } else {
            document.location.href = url_all_params;
        }
    }
}
```

To the code above:

1. Find the parameter you are looking for
2. When you find it, save it in a cookie
3. If you haven't found it, see if the cookie exists
4. If the cookie exists, get the parameter you are looking for and add
   it to the URL
5. If the cookie doesn't exist, do nothing

This will make the `referring_site` look like this in the order webhook:

`"referring_site": https://{shop}.myshopify.com/products/testprodukt-1/?myparam=1`

Now you can do what you want with the parameter in the backend, I hope I could help or provide inspiration.